# Grothendiecks's lectures on Kohärente Garben und verallgemeinerte Riemann-Roch-Hirzebruch Formel

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ho.history-overview

In his biography of Hirzebruch in [Jahresber Dtsch Math-Ver (2015) 117:93–132](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1365/s13291-015-0114-1/dmv-FH.pdf), Zagier says that

> [T]he dominating event [of the first Arbeitstagung in 1957] was unquestionably Grothendieck’s lecture series “Kohärente Garben und verallgemeinerte
> Riemann-Roch-Hirzebruch Formel auf algebraischen Mannigfaltigkeiten” in which,
> in a total of 12 hours of talks, filling all of Saturday afternoon and Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday mornings, Grothendieck presented his generalization of the
> Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem.

Are the notes of these lectures available somewhere ?  Perhaps in the Hirzebruch papers at Max Planck ?

Comment: This preprint suggests (to me) that Zagier would reply to email sent for him at Max Planck  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.03568.pdf